# How to get not get an error if custom image attribute image isn't there?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-images, custom-attributes

I'm trying to add an image link to the head of my pages. This code below works except if the image isn't there, I've tried a lot of different ways but no luck.  The part `<?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>` works fine on it's on but it doesn't get the correct image, so I'm using it to fall back on if the other image isn't there. But I keep getting errors and the page goes blank if the image isn't there. Here's my latest attempt.

```
<?php if (($this->helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'twitter_image')) != null): ?>
    <?php $twitter_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'twitter_image'); ?> 
    <?php if ($twitter_image): ?><?php echo $twitter_image; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: are u trying on product page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `getimagesize`

```
    <?php if (getimagesize($twitter_image)!== false): ?><?php echo $twitter_image; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

another solution

```
<?php $products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::registry('current_product')->getId());
if ($products->getTwitterImage()): ?>
<?php $twitter_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'twitter_image'); ?> 
<?php echo $twitter_image; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all, errors everywhere, even if the image is there. : )

Comment: @Freejoy added another solution..

Comment: No, still doesn't work. If I use this it works on the pages with the image and blanks out if the image isn't there: <?php $twitter_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'twitter_image'); ?> 
    <?php if ($twitter_image): ?><?php echo $twitter_image; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>  It gets the correct image too.

Comment: added the way from registry  and also check your attribute is loading or not `twitter_image`

Comment: you have to check for value before getting the image otherwise you will get the error.

Comment: added the code kindly check and feedback

Comment: Yes, that works. It doesn't get the correct  "fallback Image" i.e. <?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>,  earlier I read I needed a placeholder image and on the pages without the twitter image it gets the placeholder image. That kind of surprised me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your error log / php logs to see what's killed the page.

What looks weird to me immediately is this line:

`<?php if (($this->helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'twitter_image')) != null): ?>`

This is the function you're calling:

`/**
135      * Initialize Helper to work with Image
136      *
137      * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
138      * @param string $attributeName
139      * @param mixed $imageFile
140      * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
141      */
142     public function init(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeName, $imageFile=null)`

It doesn't ever return null, it returns an instance of Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image. If you want to check if the product has the attribute you're better off doing something like

`$_product = Mage::registry('current_product);
if ($product && $product->getTwitterImage()) {
}`

Comment: No errors but it didn't get a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please try below code.

<?php
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$twitter_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'twitter_image')->resize(100);
    if($twitter_image != '' && $twitter_image != 'no_selection'){
    ?>
    <img src='<php echo$twitter_image ; ?>' />
    <?php
    }
?>
```